# MVVM Light - ViewModelLocator, set Propertys

Tags: c#, properties, viewmodel, mvvm-light, viewmodellocator

Hello I need help with mvvm light.

I want to set properties in my constructor. But its calling only once.
I have a viewModel and a view. I call the viewModel from another viewModel through ViewModelLocator. On the first time, when i call the viewModel all works fine, but when i call the viewModel in other times it doesn't work, because it was created the viewModel and its constructor already called. How can i reset(or whatever) the viewModelLocator so he call the constructor every time when i call the viewModelLocator.

In the code below, i am calling another viewModel:

```
var viewModel= (new ViewModelLocator()).TestVM;
viewModel.Item = _item;
Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage("testView"));
```

Comment: Is your Locator and ViewModels inside are `static`?

Answer (score 0):

MVVMLight's `ViewModelLocator` isn't designed to be instanciated directly in your code. Inside its contructor you should register all dependencies you know. Your ViewModels would then take all dependencies as constructor parameters like this:

```
public MainViewModel(IMessenger messenger, IDialogService dialogService)
{
    // Use messenger and dialogService
    // ...
}
```

When you set a ViewModel as a `DataContext` in a View using your locator instance, the ViewModelLocator tries to resolve all neccessary dependencies.

Please note that the default behavior of the `SimpleIoc` container is to cache all created objects, so none of your constructors will be called twice.